# How to add properties to MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I want to extend additional user registration fields, and other tutorial suggested the way to do this is to use the profile-properties. (?)

So I add a section to the Web.config file, as shown below ( tag), and I expected Profile to be available by intellisense in the .cs files, but it's not..

So how to make this work?  And are there better solutions to this?

Btw, the tutorial was [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylEE4b6Sv7o&feature=player_detailpage#t=84s).

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="Age"/>
    <add name="Gender" />
  </properties>

  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>

</profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`ProfileProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx) instead. It's designed to extend additional properties against the `MembershipUser`.

You can then strong type access to the Profile. If your are using the Web site project this is code generated for you from your config settings. Web Application project you need to do this manually, or use [external tools](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=980). This [article](http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/) has some useful info.